# Gaining and losing life at the same time

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a question about a specific scenario involving life loss and gain.

Say I have 3 life left, the creature [Soulcage Fiend](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=240150) on the battlefield, and also the enchantment [Exquisite Blood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=240134) on the battlefield.

Now say my opponent kills Soulcage Fiend with some instant, would I lose the game? Or does the gain of life happen first, keeping me at 3 life when all is said and done?

Comment: It's worth noting that in this scenario you don't gain and lose life at the same time. First you lose the life, then only later, you gain the life (if you haven't already lost).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word "whenever" usually means that the card triggers, which goes on the stack.

From the Oracle Text for Exquisite Blood:

> If you and an opponent both lose life simultaneously, and this causes your life total to become 0 or less, you'll lose the game before Exquisite Blood's triggered ability can resolve.

You would lose the game.